# ClassCastException while using Java Reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I'm working with a stub that receives data from the skeleton:

```
MethodCallMessage reply = messageManager.wReceive();
        String returnString = reply.getParameter("result.string");
        int returnInt = Integer.parseInt(reply.getParameter("result.integer"));
        char returnChar = reply.getParameter("result.character").charAt(0);
        boolean returnBool = Boolean.valueOf(reply.getParameter("result.bool"));
        System.out.println("String return value in Invocation Handler: " + returnString);
        System.out.println("Int return value in Invocation Handler: " + returnInt);
        System.out.println("Char value in Invocation Handler: " + String.valueOf(returnChar));
        System.out.println("Bool value in Invocation Handler: " + String.valueOf(returnBool));
```

Then I try to create an instance of a class which is in a different package:

```
Class c = Class.forName(method.getReturnType().getName());
c.newInstance();
```

I can get to the methods so I thought everything was dandy:

```
Method[] methods = c.getDeclaredMethods();
        System.out.println("size: " + methods.length);
        for(Method method1: methods){
            System.out.println(method1.getName());
            if(method1.getReturnType().getSimpleName().equals("string")){
                System.out.println("heir");
                method1.invoke(c, returnString);
            }
            if(method1.getReturnType().getSimpleName().equals("int")){
                method1.invoke(c, returnInt);
            }
            if(method1.getReturnType().getSimpleName().equals("char")){
                method1.invoke(c, returnChar);
            }
            if(method1.getReturnType().getSimpleName().equals("boolean")){
                method1.invoke(c, returnBool);
            }

        }
```

and at the end of it all I return the object:

```
return c;
```

But then I get:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to be.kdg.distrib.testclasses.TestObject
```

The package is what I pass trough the Class.forName() .
How come I can get to the methods and fields but can cast it?

**EDIT:**

To clarify, this code is written in a StubInvocationHandler and is meant to pass the following test:

```
@Test
public void testWithObjectReturnValue() {
    testSkeleton.sendObjectReturnValue();
    TestInterface stub = (TestInterface) StubFactory.createStub(TestInterface.class, "127.0.0.1", port);
    TestObject test = stub.testMethod11();
    MethodCallMessage message = testSkeleton.getMessage();
    assertEquals("testMethod11", message.getMethodName());
    assertEquals(0, message.getParameters().size());
    assertEquals('r', test.getCharacter());
    assertEquals("bloop", test.getString());
    assertEquals(123, test.getInteger());
    assertTrue(test.isBool());
}
```

And here is the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

Comment: Please post the full method, in the form of a [mcve]. In any case, it looks like you are returning the `Class`, not the object you created...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use raw types! Use `Class<?>` instead of `Class`!

The main problem is that you pass in `c` as the objects to call the methods on. `c` is of type `Class`, definitely not the type where the methods you want to call are declared :)

You seem to know that an instance has to be created to call the methods by calling `c.newInstance`, but you forgot to assign to a variable:

```
Object instance = c.newInstance();
```

You should pass `instance`, not `c`.

Also, are you sure returning `c` is correct? From your test, it seems `testMethod11` should return a `TestObject`, which means that the `instance` should be retuned instead.

Comment: You're too perceptive to be defied even by a poor question.

Comment: That was it, but now I get an error that I have the wrong number of arguments for my invoke method, eventhough the setter only takes 1 parameter?

Comment: @Audiosleef Maybe `getDeclaredMethods` returned some methods that you don't expect? Print out the names and parameter counts of the methods in the `methods` array.

Comment: Only getters and setters, and the getters return void so they should be skippen. Seeing as the error occurs at the invoke method, the return types are recognized?

Comment: @Audiosleef seeing statements like `if(method1.getReturnType().equals(Boolean.class) && method1.getReturnType().toString().startsWith("set")){ method1.invoke(c, returnBool); }` in your code, I’m wondering whether you understood the difference between *return* type and *parameter* type and, even worse, whether you understood the difference between *return type* and the *method name*.

Comment: @Holger I noticed that just now! So how are the `invoke` calls called in the first place? The if statements will all fail!

Comment: I've edited my post with the new if methods and the updated stacktrace

Comment: @Audiosleef You should try debugging this. Try printing the parameter count of the method before every `invoke` call. Or even better, set an exception breakpoint if your IDE supports that. Then you can inspect what's wrong with the method.

Comment: I added a line and I get into the if where int is the return type. There he invokes the method where I pass the instance and the int itself, but there I get the error.

Comment: @Audiosleef You should print `method.getParameterCount` and see if it is 1.

Comment: @Sweeper You were right, It was trying to invoke a method that doesnt take any parameters. Do you know a better way to distinguish the getters from the setters?

Comment: @Audiosleef Check if `getParameterCount == 1`?

Comment: @Sweeper but I also have to distinguish them by return type

Comment: @Audiosleef is there any reason why you can’t check both? With the && operator?

Comment: @Sweeper well yes, i'm doing method1.getParameterCount() == 1 && method1.getReturnType().equals(Integer.class) now but the check on the return type but it doesn't get into the if statements anymore so the check on the return type is no good

Comment: @Audiosleef you need `int.class`. And I think this discussion has gone out of the scope of the question. I suggest you look some stuff up first, and ask another question.

Comment: @Sweeper I got it to work, thanks alot for your help :)